# Caret jump over several character when it reach end of textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, caret

I am using a textbox in c# windows application, WinForms. When the text in the textbox is longer than textbox's width then only a portion of the text is shown. To see the rest of the text you must scroll the text by moving the caret.

For example, imagine a textbox with the text `stackoverflow.com/questions`, but the textbox currently shows just `stackoverflow.c` because it is too narrow. Now, when I put with caret between `.` and `c` and then move the caret right with the keyboard, now the textbox will show `overflow.com/qu` because it has scrolled the textbox right by five characters. However, I only want the textbox to scroll by one character so that it shows `tackoverflow.co`.

How can I control how many characters the textbox scrolls when moving the caret causes the textbox to scroll?

```
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from league where id = 1", conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBoxWebPage.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: please edit the question and put the code in it